# webHttpBinding endpoint adds temuri.org namespace in WSDL if bindingNamespace attribute is excluded

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wshttpbinding, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF service that needs to be exposed over a SOAP endpoint (wsHttpBinding) and a REST endpoint (webHttpBinding).  I have included Names and Namespaces on the relevant attributes to aid in versioning (tempuri.org should be completely eliminated from the WSDL).  For some reason, if I don't add a bindingNamepace attribute on the webHttpBinding endpoint, it adds a tempuri.org namespace in the WSDL.  Example WSDL output is below.

WSDL without bindingNamespace -

```
<wsdl:definitions name="State" targetNamespace="http://example.com/services/masterdat/state/2012/02/05" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:tns="http://example.com/services/masterdata/state/2012/02/05" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:i0="http://tempuri.org/"
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
```

WSDL with bindingNamespace -

```
<wsdl:definitions name="State" targetNamespace="http://example.com/services/masterdata/state/2012/02/05" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:tns="http://example.com/services/masterdata/state/2012/02/05" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
```

Here is my web.Config for the endpoints.  I am using WCFExtras to flatten my WSDLs (hence the behaviorConfiguration on the wsHttpBinding endpoint), but the behavior is the same without it.

```
<services>
  <service name="MasterDataExample.Services.StateService">
    <!--  bindingConfiguration="defaultWsBinding" -->
    <endpoint address="soap"
              behaviorConfiguration="flatWsdl"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="http://example.com/services/masterdata/state/2012/02/05"
              contract="MasterDataExample.Services.IStateService" 
              name="soap" />
    <!--  -->
    <endpoint address="json"
              behaviorConfiguration="json"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="http://example.com/services/masterdata/state/2012/02/05"
              contract="MasterDataExample.Services.IStateService" 
              name="ajax" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I've loaded up WCFExtras in my solution and looked at the WsdlExporter to see if I can find the mention of tempuri.org with no success.  I've also used XSharper.Core to dump the object graph to see if I could find it.  It isn't there.

Has anyone experienced this before?  As a work around, I'll include the bindingNamespace on the webHttpBinding endpoint to keep the WSDL clean, but I'd like to know why this is occurring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the BindingNamespace is required in your endpoint configuration to remove the tempuri.org namespace completely from your WSDL. See [this post](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-get-rid-of-httptempuriorg-in-wcf.html) (item 3).